# How do I get the date to print only the day of the week?

Tags: javascript

How do i print only the date of the week with JS. Or maybe the day and month?

I was playing around with some functions but I only get the whole date.

```
let today = new Date()
today.getDate()

let tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.getDay(today.getDate()+1)
```

Then I will have to use the variable as props in a react component and it should be a string.
So should I use toUTCstring?

Comment: What's "date of the week", do you want the day, as in "sunday", and month as "may" etc ?

Comment: Yes, either the day in number or words. I know I can do that with  toLocaleString() to but I don't know how to get rid of the time.

Comment: Did you try `getDay`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `weekday` option of [`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString):

```
mydateobject.toLocaleString("en", { weekday: "long" })
```

The month name can be got in a similar way:

```
mydateobject.toLocaleString("en", { month: "long" })
```

Answer (score 2):

`getDay` takes no arguments. You're looking for `setDate` to set the date to tomorrow, and then use `getDay` without arguments:

```js
let tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
let days = ['sun', 'mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat']
console.log('tomorrow is: ' + days[tomorrow.getDay()])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `getDay()` method. This will return a number. You can use this number to get the name of the day. Something like this

```
var days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];

let date = new Date();
var day_of_week = date.getDay();
var day_name = days[day_of_week];
```

Answer (score 1):

the javascript Date object has many methods to get what you want: you can use [getDay()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date/getDay) to get the day of the week and [getMonth()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date/getMonth) to get the month.

To pass this as a string parameter I believe the best would be to use [toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date/toISOString) and you can use this string as a parameter to the Date constructor on the other side.

Answer (score 1):

For handling dates I recommend using [moment js](https://momentjs.com) library

you can install it with `npm install moment` and then

```
moment().format('E');
```

or

```
moment().utc.().format('E');
```

or just `moment().day()`

Answer (score 1):

Using [Date.toDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString) you can format into dd mmm yy (or any way you want):

```
let date = new Date
str = date.toDateString() // 'Mon May 06 2019
let arr = str.split(" ") // ['Mon', 'May', '06', '2019']
let formatted = parseInt(arr[2]).toString() + " " + arr[1] + " " + arr[3] //6 May 2019
console.log(formatted) //6 May 2019
```

Using [Date.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) gives weekday:

```
let date = new Date
let weekdayLong = date.toLocaleString('en-gb', {weekday: 'long'}) //Monday
let weekdayShort = date.toLocaleString('en-gb', {weekday: 'short'}) //Mon
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `toDateString` will always return the 3 letters of the day if the week, so you can:

```js
// Today
new Date().toDateString().substring(0,3)
// Tomorrow
new Date(Date.now()+24*3600*1e3).toDateString().substring(0,3)
```

Or, to get the number (zero based):

```js
// Today
new Date().getDay()
// Tomorrow
new Date(Date.now()+24*3600*1e3).getDay()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use momentjs library, you can use `let day = moment(tomorrow).format('dddd');`

```
let tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
console.log(tomorrow)
let day = moment(tomorrow).format('dddd');
console.log(day);
```

```js
let tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
console.log(tomorrow)
let day = moment(tomorrow).format('dddd');
console.log(day);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js"></script>
```